# ComponentOne MediaPlayer WPF Control: MediaItem's Duration in Playlist display "00:00:00"?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using C1MediaPlayer WPF Control. Now i got a problem in displaying the Media's Duration in Player's Playlist,

```
C1MediaItem MediaClip = new C1MediaItem();
MediaClip.MediaSource = new Uri(MediaPath);
MediaClip.Title = title;    
MediaPlayerControl.Items.Add(MediaClip);
```

When i open the Playlist, my item's Duration is "00:00:00".

I want to set my item's Duration to it's full length not "00:00:00", Please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the NaturalDuration property to the length of the video. 
To do this, right click on the C1MediaPlayer and select Properties. Scroll down to 'Items' collection and click on ellipses. Select the mediaItem from the left pane, and set the NaturalDuration on the right pane. Or you can just set the property in XAML thus:

```
NaturalDuration="00:28:15"
```

I've also posted a sample app at [this](http://publicfiles.componentone.com/Mateen/C1WPF%20MediaPlayer.zip) link for your reference.

Comment: But I don't want to set it manually, i want to it automatically display